# Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS/ArcGIS Online web app issues

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I have created a a few web apps through ArcGIS Online and although I have shared each with "Everyone (public)", the URL I sent to a colleague brings up the ArcGIS Online sign in page. It seems as if the functionality of sharing apps has changed since the last time I visited our AGOL site. For instance, I no longer see the option to "embed" a map.

Here is an example of the url:

http://uncw.maps.arcgis.com/apps/OnePane/basicviewer/...

Here is the example from a test app created with AppBuilder:

/apps/webappviewer/index.html?...

Does anyone know why I cannot create a valid URL (that does not require a log in) from my shared ArcGIS Online web apps?

Comment: please edit our original question and provide an actual question.

Comment: The Web Map Application can be public, but one of the Map Layers included in the map can be a secure Map Service (published on an ArcGIS Server). If that's the case, it will prompt you for credentials (of the provided ArcGIS Server) for acessing that particular service. If authentication fails, it will give you access to the Web Map Application, but it won't show that particular secure map service.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue a few weeks ago, and I had to change a security setting on ArcGIS Online. Sign into ArcGIS online, then go to "My Organization" link on the top. From there, click on "Edit Settings". On Edit Settings, click on the "Security" tab on the left side column. I checked the second check box down "Allow anonymous access to your organization's website. (Your Organizations Name)." (See screen shot). ESRI also has a link to a support article by the security option:

http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/share-items.htm

[image]

Comment: Thanks Brian - I will try this. Thanks for the link as well.

Answer (score 0):

http://uncw.maps.arcgis.com/apps/OnePane/basicviewer/

Ya, just take out HTTP:  and uncw.maps.arcgis.com

It should read  //arcgis.com/apps/OnePane/Basicviewer/

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the short [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format. We are looking for longer answers that (ideally) provide some context and references. Also, //arcgis.com/apps/OnePane/Basicviewer/ is not a valid URL.